# Subclass.fetchRequest() Swift 3.0, extension not really helping 100%?

Tags: swift, core-data

according to the new Core Data changes, Xcode generates this subclass for me:

```
extension Person {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Person> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person");
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?

}
```

then in code I was expecting to have this one line working:

```
let fr = Person.fetchRequest()
```

This line of code above however gives me an error:

```
"Ambiguous use of 'fetchRequest'
```

This fixes the issue:

```
let fr: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
```

So then, I am confused what is the:

```
NSFetchRequest<Person>
```

in the:

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Person> {
```

return type doing at all?

Shouldn't the return type allow me not to have to specify the:

```
NSFetchRequest<Person>
```

in the let definition??

```
let fr: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
```

Can anybody help me understand why it is needed even though it's part of the return type already?

Comment: I understand the reasoning with the answers mentioned here, but I don't understand, WHY WOULD APPLE ADD NON COMPILING CODE!! /rant over

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The reason this is happening is there are two methods named `fetchRequest` in your `Person` class:

- first is in your model subclass (`Person`) with return type `NSFetchRequest<Person>`
- second is in `NSManagedObject` with return type `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>`

That's actually why it is ambiguous, compiler does not know which out of 2 you refer to. If you rename func name in your `Person+CoreDataProperties` to from `fetchRequest` to `personFetchRequest` and call by that name - it would compile just like that.

Even better - just add another func to your `Person+CoreDataClass` with different name, which would return `Person.fetchRequest()`, and you won't need to cast when calling by that name.

Answer (score 23):

Because fetchRequest() is generic for all entity,you can see same method in all your generated extensions , you have to make it specific .

Below line is specific to **YourEntity** class fetch request method

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<**YourEntity**> = **YourEntity**.fetchRequest()
```