# CoreData one to many relationship comparing to value

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two entities:

AgendaEvents

AgendaDates

AgendaDates has a one to many relationship with AgendaEvents.

I am trying to store in a temporary array (var myTempEvents = [AgendaEvent] ())
all the AgendaEvents which have inside AgendaDates a date which is equal to a defined date (let myDate = Date() )

So far I have this:

```
 var myEventDate = [String]()
 var myTempEvents = [AgendaEvent]()
 var myEvents = [AgendaEvent]()
 var myDate = Date()

 func getEventDates() {
    for event in myEvents {
        for date in (event.agendaDates as? Set<AgendaDate>)! {
            let eventDates = date.agendaDates
            eventDate = eventDates
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"
            let eventDateString = formatter.string(from: eventDate)
            myEventDate.append(eventDateString)

        }
    }
}
```

What I would need to do now is to check if an AgendaEvents has a date which is equal to myDate, if so i would need to add that event to myTempEvents.

This should happen inside this function:

```
func configureCell(cell: CalendarAgendaCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    for dates in calendar.selectedDates {
        for dateOfEvent in myEventDate {
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"
            let dateToCompare = formatter.string(from: dates)
            if dateOfEvent == dateToCompare {
                let myEvent = myTempEvents[indexPath.row]
                cell.configureCell(agendaEvent: myEvent)

            } else {
                //empty the tempArray

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this function is called by the cellForRowAt func for tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Dequeue Cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AgendaCell", for: indexPath) as! AgendaCell
    //Fetch model object to display
    configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

I am not very good at core data (still learning) so any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

UPDATE---------14/09/17

As @Simo kindly suggested I've edited my code like so:

```
    func agendaEventsWithDate(date: Date) -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
{
    // create a fetch request that will retrieve all the AgendaEvents.
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AgendaEvent")

    // set the predicate to only keep AgendaEvents where the related AgendaDate's date matches the passed in date.
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY agendaDates.agendaDates == %@", date as CVarArg)

    return fetchRequest
}

 let myTempEvents = try?context.fetch(agendaEventsWithDate(date: Date()))
```

where context is:

```
let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext

However i'm getting this error:

Ambiguous use of 'fetch'

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to achieve this without having to do the comparison yourself. You should read up on using `NSFetchRequest` with predicates.

You could fetch all the `AgendaEvent` stored in Core Data and then filter them so that you are left with only the events that contain an `AgendaDate` that matches your specified date.

The fetch request (wrapped up in a nice provider function) would probably look something like:

```
func agendaEventsWithDate(date: Date) -> NSFetchRequest
{
    // create a fetch request that will retrieve all the AgendaEvents.
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "AgendaEvent")

    // set the predicate to only keep AgendaEvents where the related AgendaDate's date matches the passed in date. 
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY agendaDates.date == %@", date)

    return fetchRequest
}
```

This obviously assumes that your `AgendaEvent` entity's relationship to `AgendaDate` is called `agendaDates` and also that your `AgendaDate` entity has an attribute called `date`.

Then when you execute the fetch request you will then be returned an array of the items you were looking for. No need for all the manual comparison that you are doing.

```
let myTempEvents = try? managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(self.agendaEventsWithDate(someDate))
```

Comment: do you mean to use this: let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext;  let myTempEvents = try? context.execute(self.agendaEventsWithDate(date: somedate))

Comment: Well you can access your managed object context from wherever you want. Personally I don't setup my Core Data stack in the app delegate as there are much cleaner ways to do it, but that's another topic itself.

Comment: ok thanks... I am trying to do as you suggested... but i get this: Ambiguous use of 'fetch'. I'll edit my question to show exactly what i've done...

Comment: Ah sorry, my code example was written from memory and wasn't very Swift 3. If you change your fetch request to `let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<AgendaEvent>(entityName: "AgendaEvent")` that should help you. There's some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42032539/273082) that explain why you're getting the ambiguous error.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.. but still not working... :( have edited the fetchrequest as u've suggested and needed to add also myTempEvents... as [AgendaEvent]... but i got a crash as soon as i build the app... is it possibile that this is due because the AgendaEvent as also a relationship one to many with another entity? (the relationship is swimminpool and is the one..)

Comment: My bad...i had changed the relation to one to many.. and i actually set it at the beginning as many to many... that's why was crashing.... now the app it's working... but myTempEvents is always empty...

Comment: Try commenting out the fetch request's predicate. If myTempEvents is still empty, then you have no AgendaEvents stored in Core Data. If you do get some returned then it means that no AgendaEvents have the exact same matching date.

Comment: Yes i think this is the problem... the AgendaDate is in the format "yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss" and the date i need to compare is in the format "dd MM yyyy". I am trying to remove the time from teh AgendaDate but it seems more complicated then i've expected... :)