# iOS swift core data persistence problem: Lost and thrashing

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I may have done a really stupid thing.

In writing an upgrade for my (first) shipped app, I changed the schema of my Core Data model, adding another entity (`Issuer`) and creating a `to-many` relationship with the existing entity (`Coin`). I thought the lightweight migration had successfully taken care of the change:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Here's the Core Data stack, created automatically when I created the project:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Coin_Portfolio")
    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()

    description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
    description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
    })
    return container
}()
```

In testing on my iPhone, I found that I could create `Coin`s, like this:

```
func createNewCoin(){
    
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    newCoin = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Coin", into: context) as! Coin
    
    
    if currentOwner.name == nil {
        print("In NewCoin, createNewCoin, currentOwner is nil")
        
    }else{
        print("In NewCoin, createNewCoin, currentOwner is named \(String(describing: currentOwner.name))")
    }
    
    
    // Problem with contexts could be here! Compare DB for this app to test bed
    
    
    newCoin.denomination = nil
    newCoin.grade = nil
    newCoin.itemIdentifier = ""
    newCoin.mintMark = nil
    currentOwner.addToCoins(newCoin)
    
    saveIt()
    
}

func saveIt(){
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    appDelegate.saveContext()
}
```

And retrieve it like this:

```
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let ownerFetchRequest :
            NSFetchRequest<Issuer> = Issuer.fetchRequest()

        do {
            try ownerFRC?.performFetch()
            owners = try context.fetch(ownerFetchRequest)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }
            
            for owner in owners{
                if owner.name == currentOwner.name{
                    currentOwnerCoinsByDenom = ((owner.coins?.allObjects as! [Coin]).sorted(by: { $0.denomination! < $1.denomination! }))
                    currentOwnerCoinsByYear = ((currentOwnerCoinsByDenom as! [Coin]).sorted(by: { $0.denomination! < $1.denomination! }))
                    
                    print ("currentOwnerCoinsByDenom.count == \(currentOwnerCoinsByDenom)")
                    print(currentOwnerCoinsByDenom.count)
                    
                    print ("currentOwnerCoinsByYear.count == \(currentOwnerCoinsByYear)")
                    print(currentOwnerCoinsByYear.count)
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Fine, as long as I don't quit the app and relaunch it.
Upon relaunch, my fetch attempts return no `Coin`s, even though I know that there had been some 80+ records stored in Core Data before the schema change.

I then started what I thought was a rational approach to solving the problem. See [iOS data saved in Core Data doesn't survive launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667160/ios-data-saved-in-core-data-doesnt-survive-launch). The answers received, unfortunately, didn't solve the problem.

Accordingly, I panicked, knowing my users wouldn't take kindly to losing their own records.

Here's where I may have run off the rails: I created a duplicate project in order to try to resolve the issue without screwing up my original. But I continue to experience the same problem.

I have examined the dataBase(s) using DB Browser for SQLite, but am very confused as to which DB I'm downloading -- is it the original, or the one created by the duplicate project? They both have the same name, but one of them has the original records, the other only one record.

Any ideas how I can save myself? I'm flummoxed and desperate! Will gladly supply any needed info or code.

All help deeply appreciated!

Comment: I don't have any useful tech stuff to say at the moment, but...do you have source available that matches your working app from before the schema change?  (Source control?  Time Machine?  ...?)  That would be a good step toward a non-panic migration solution.

Comment: Away from the Mac at the moment, but am sure I do. I’ve tried isolating any other copies, so that may help.

Comment: @PhillipMills-- OK, I've backed up in Git until the app is able to fetch the records in Core Data! Of course, it's using the old schema, not compatible with the desired product. Also, it crashes because of the length of an array, and I suspect I'll find many more issues like that. Be very grateful if you have the time, and can suggest my next step forward. If needed, I think I can push the whole enchilada to Github. Many thanks!